# Checkstyle 'this' keyword overuse detection

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is there a Checkstyle module to detect code like this

```
private ServiceClass service = ...

public void someMethod(String param) {
    String result = this.service.find(param);
    if(!this.isValid(result)) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } else {
        return result;
    }
} 

private boolean isValid(String param) {
...
}
```

As you can see here `this` isn't needed actually as there are no any method and field overlappings.

The [RequireThis](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#RequireThis) module is close to my needs but looks like it can't detect such kind of over usage.

Answer (score 2):

> this isn't needed actually as there are no any method and field overlappings.

There is no Checkstyle check that flags unnecessary usage of `this`. `RequireThis` check only identifies areas missing `this`, not the reverse.